# Emacs M-x binding in Mac M1

Tags: emacs, apple-m1

In emacs M-x binding-name can be used for running a command.

However in Mac M1, for some reason, this is not working.

Basically, I am trying option + x or M-x.

Any idea about this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Ask Different.

Comment: Or perhaps on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.